# How do i speed up this SQL query for an Access DB Using OLEDB

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am attempting to retrieve one field of one row in an access database. The current setup i have takes around 100 ms. Is there a faster way for a single field?

```
    Public Function GetEntityConfig(ByVal pintID As Integer) As aadXML.XMLDoc
    Dim objRtn As New aadXML.XMLDoc, myreader As OleDbDataReader


    Dim Query As New OleDbCommand("Select e_config from entity where e_id = " & pintID, CurrentActiveConnectionToDB)
    If CurrentActiveConnectionToDB.State = False Then
        CurrentActiveConnectionToDB.Open()
    End If
    myreader = Query.ExecuteReader()

    myreader.Read()
    objRtn.LoadXML(myreader.Item("e_config"))
    myreader.Close()
    GetEntityConfig = objRtn

    CurrentActiveConnectionToDB.Close()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should learn to use parameters, rather than munging a query string with input values.

Your query is:

```
Select e_config
from entity
where e_id = ?
```

For this query, an index will speed it up:

```
create index idx_entity_e_d_e_config on entity(e_id, e_config);
```

You don't have to include `e_config` in the index; it is helpful but only marginal.

Comment: @Prime . . . You didn't find that this helped?